# Intro page for new private beta sites contains incorrect sentence about going public

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, wording, beta-sites, private-beta

When signing into a new private beta site for the first time, there's a gatekeeper screen that looks like this:

[image: Gatekeeper screen shown when visiting a private beta site for the first time]

At the end of this message, there's a sentence that says:

> We expect this site to go public in a few days.

This sentence is incorrect, for two reasons:

1. For a while now, private betas have been lasting three weeks (to get at least 150 high-quality questions), with the possibility of shortening to two weeks if the required questions are reached earlier. It's not accurate during at least the first week of private beta (if not the first two weeks) to say that it will go live "in a few days".
2. If the site fails to reach the required threshold within those three weeks, it won't advance past private beta, meaning that it won't "go public". Saying that you "expect the site to go live in [some time]" is not accurate if there's a possibility that it won't end up going live if it fails to meet the requirement.

Can the sentence please be changed to something like:

> Provided the private beta succeeds, we expect this site to go live within the next 2-3 weeks.

...with the "2-3 weeks" changing to "1-2 weeks" one week in, and changing to "a few days" two weeks in?

(It used to be that private betas were one week with the possibility of being extended to two weeks if it wasn't going as well, but the current model is as above.)

Comment: Or sometimes within 2-3 years.

Comment: I think the best solution is to just remove that line completely. It seems unreasonable to continue saying anything about the timeframe when there are too many variables to account for.

Comment: @animuson How about just using the word "soon" instead?

Comment: Change it to "Soon™"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first and last paragraphs on the page have been updated. They now read the following:

[image: image highlighting the areas where text was updated]

The date at the bottom is generated based on when the site entered private beta.